# How to use Google Analytics in a JavaScript Web Application that has file:/// URI

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a front-end only JavaScript web application (used technologies are HTML5, CSS and JavaScript). This application is injected into a mobile application, that takes my JS web app and displays it in a fancy way.

I would like to track user's activities in my app using Google Analytics, but **the problem is that my JS application injected into the mobile app doesn't have a regular URL** that is needed when using GA for websites / web apps, but **it's also not a mobile application** to try GA for mobile apps.. The result is a hybrid between mobile and web application and I can only edit my JS application.

I have made the following image to visualize my problem better.

[image]

Using [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com) I can programatically access my app and also check its console even when it is uploaded in iPresent. There are no errors. If I alert the app's URL, I got file URI:

```
alert( $( location ).attr( 'href ') );

//returns file:///var/mobile/..../index.html
```

I have tried many solutions-wanna-be (i.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591847/google-analytics-from-a-file-url) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502128/convert-google-analytics-cookies-to-local-session-storage)), none of them works. But I am a beginner at this field, just blindly attempting to solve this, so probably missed some important note. **Cookies works fine in my apps in iPresent.**

My last GA code I used:

```
    <script>

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    if(window.localStorage) {
        ga('create', 'UA-NUMBER-1', 'none', {
          'storage': 'none'
          , 'clientId': window.localStorage.getItem('ga_clientId')
        });
        ga(function(tracker) {
          window.localStorage.setItem('ga_clientId', tracker.get('clientId'));
        });
    }
    else {
        ga('create', 'UA-NUMBER-1', 'none');
    }
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

**Is it possible to make GA work with this hybrid web application that doesn't have a regular URL, but file URI? If so, how?**

Thank u!

Comment: Have you checked you GA-Account/Property if there really is nothing tracked? I mean, that the file:// URLs are not just tracked same way as http:// URLs?

Comment: If I add the file:///.... address in the service settings, it gives me an error due to an invalid URL address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en). It will allow you to track most, if not all, interactions that the Google Analtycis JavaScript does using HTTP requests to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect.

Here is a pure JavaScript example of how to make the request using GET:

```
var hit = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?';
    hit += 'v=1';                 // Version.
    // Be sure to update the tid, Tracking ID, with your Google Analytics Tracking ID.
    hit += '&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y';     // Tracking ID / Property ID.
    hit += '&cid=555';            // Anonymous Client ID.
    hit += '&t=pageview';         // Pageview hit type.
    hit += '&dh=mydemo.com';      // Document hostname.
    hit += '&dp=/home';           // Page.
    hit += '&dt=homepage';        // Title.

httpGetRequest(hit);

function httpGetRequest(theUrl)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", theUrl, true);
    req.send(null);
}
```

You should look at [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript) and [Eloquent JavaScript Second Edition - Chapter 17 HTTP](http://eloquentjavascript.net/17_http.html) for more information about sending HTTP requests using JavaScript. If you have access to jQuery then you could also use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Once your request has been made you can log in to your Google Analytics account and see the pageview within Reporting. You can either see it in your Real-Time >> Overview or in Behavior >> Site Content >> All Pages.

[image]

In the image above I went to Behavior >> Site Content >> All Pages, shown in red. Then I set my date range to October 21, 2015, shown in blue. The highlighted portion shows the **Document hostname** and **Page** that I set in the JavaScript *hit* variable. Note that I have a filter that updates the Page to also include the hostname so you might just see */home* for your Page.

If you have any questions, just let me know.

Comment: I have already taken a look at AMP, but I am confused how to integrate it into my project. It a basic webpage using HTML5, CSS and JS. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: I edited my answer with a pure JavaScript example and some references to get you started down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, Adam. I am trying this example and keep on getting req.status 0 and req.statusText empty. Was wondering - is the document host name, page and title in var hit to blame as I don't know the url?

Comment: I believe that I should have just omitted the `console.log` from the JavaScript. The important thing is whether or not the Pageview hit registered within your Google Analytics. I forgot to point out that you will need to replace `UA-XXXXX-Y` with your Tracking ID.

Comment: I made this work just by enhancing the url address a bit. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ helped me to create a valid hit. Thank you so much for your help!