# Can I use Firebase Analytic Web SDK for a Cordova App?

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-analytics

I'm developing a cross platform app: Web, PWA, iOS (Cordova) & Android (Cordova).

I use the same code base, and Firestore & Auth are working well on all the platforms using only the Web SDK.

However, when I add the Firebase Analytic plugin, it works as expected on the Web / PWA, but the iOS / Android apps do not seem to send back anything.

**Is there a way to make Analytic works using only the Web SDK? Or is it mandatory to use a Cordova Plugin?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Note: I'm using Framework7 & VueJS

---

#### Edit 1

It seems that cordova is officially supported for analytic with the web SDK.

**So the question becomes: do you have any idea why the implementation is working for "normal" app and break when on cordova?**

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#other_environments

---

#### Edit 2

Now that I know that it should work, I'm trying harder to find solutions.

First, I observed in the Safari Console that on y web app, I can observe calls to https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect every time I'm logging an event.

I do not observe those calls on the Cordova app, which is most probably the reason why I do not receive anything in my Firebase Analytics.

**The question becomes: why are those call not made in cordova, considering the js the same?**

---

#### Edit 3

Ok, I think I found the explanation:
[Google Analytics from a file:// url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591847/google-analytics-from-a-file-url/47251006#47251006)

**The question becomes: since Analytic is loaded automatically with firebase, how can I make this configuration?**

Ideally, I would like a way to set the client id using a hash of my user uuid (as I said in my post, I'm using Firebase Auth).

How can I dynamically change the value each time a user connect to the app? Can Firebase directly take care of this?